# how to read data from MySQL databases based on select input in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

can anyone help me like how to read data from database in this case,i have used MySQL databases loaded with iris dataset,when i select species type based on the select input in the shinyapp,i need to get all the data related to particular input set....sharing the code below

```
ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Iris Dataset"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("select", label = h5("select species"),choices = c("setosa", "vericolor", "virginica"), 
                  selected = "setosa")
                ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("data")
    )
  )
))

server<-shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  #referring output distPlot in ui.r as output$distPlot
  output$data <- renderText({
      query<-paste0("select * from iris where Species= '", input$select , "'", sep='')
      species<-dbGetQuery(con_iris, query)
      })
})
```

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)

And in my case i am getting only the column names only not the dataset..it would be of great help if anyone could solve this issue..?

Comment: your code works fine for me just the vericolor is misspelled - it should be versicolor

Comment: argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'  I am getting this error when i try to run it....